# Moving/self cloning carousel - Scrolling over interrupts the duplicate cloning/help on duplicating after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The carousel constantly moves and clones. When you mouse over/scroll, it removes every blue block before the red marked block. The red marked block is a reference point; when the red marked block switches, the previous block that it was just on, was the one that was cloned and appended to the bottom of the carousel.

When I scroll my mouse so that it reaches the end point of my carousel, and mouseleave the carousel; it should add duplicate slides at the end of the carousel. Instead, it has a gap below the blue blocks. I'm trying to get it so no gap appears. I'm unsure how to clone immediately the correct one when I mouseleave the carousel after the user reaches the carousel's bottom.

When I scroll up to the beginning of my carousel and mouseleave the carousel, the red marker box switches to it early; I'm trying to make it so that when the red box is 100% covered by the gray up arrow box, it switches to next one down, and the cycle repeats (like in the beginning when the carousel first started). Only difference is I need this happening correctly, after I scroll around on it.

I've tried switching the "marker" so that whenever one scrolls, *whatever* blue block's offset top position was in the range between 35 (to account for the height of the top gray box) and the negative height of a blue block plus 35, that would be the new marker; and then when you mouseleave the carousel with the new marker in place, to create the new clones without seeing carousel content that cut off. I could not achieve this.

Order doesn't matter as long as the unique six are the only ones in there when scrolling.

For JSFiddle, I tried to resize the Result part of the window so four blocks fit in there just to replicate the problem. The code should scale the contents so only four should appear at a time; but I had some trouble with JSFiddle. You may resize the Result pane to fit the four blocks to better emulate the problem.

For the JavaScript code in JSFiddle, jump down to line 223. Everything above that line is the jquery.mousewheel.js code which can be ignored. Sorry about that, I couldn't host a file under a https address at the moment.

[http://jsfiddle.net/5e77r2fw/99/](http://jsfiddle.net/5e77r2fw/98/)

HTML

```
<div id="column">
    <div class="up">
        <img src="./resources/images/up.png" alt="up arrow" />
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel -->
    <div id="carousel">
        <div class="carouselunit one">
            <div class="flipcard">
                <img class="bg-for-text" src="http://bellatortravel.com/images/g1.jpg"/>
                <div class="backpane"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carouselunit two">
            <div class="flipcard">
                <img class="bg-for-text"  src="http://bellatortravel.com/images/g2.jpg"/>
                <div class="backpane"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carouselunit three">
            <div class="flipcard">
                <img class="bg-for-text"  src="http://bellatortravel.com/images/g3.jpg"/>
                <div class="backpane"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carouselunit four">
            <div class="flipcard">
                <img class="bg-for-text"  src="http://bellatortravel.com/images/g4.jpg"/>
                <div class="backpane"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carouselunit five">
            <div class="flipcard">
                <img class="bg-for-text"  src="http://bellatortravel.com/images/g5.jpg"/>
                <div class="backpane"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carouselunit six">
            <div class="flipcard">
                <img class="bg-for-text"  src="http://bellatortravel.com/images/g6.jpg"/>
                <div class="backpane"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="down">
        <img src="./resources/images/down.png" alt="down arrow" />
    </div>
    <div class="background"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
div#column {
    top:0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid greenyellow;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 16.55%;
}
.flipcard span {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 3em;
    z-index: 3;
}
#carousel {
    border: 1px solid cyan;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    background: #000;
    padding: 35px 0px 35px 0px;
}
#carousel .carouselunit {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: auto;
}
.carouselunit.one, .carouselunit.two, .carouselunit.three, .carouselunit.four, .carouselunit.five, .carouselunit.six {
    background-color: blue;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#carousel .carouselunit.marker {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
#carousel .carouselunit .flipcard {
    border: 0px dashed pink;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    color: white;
}
#carousel > .carouselunit > .flipcard > img.bg-for-text {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    transform: translateZ(1px);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(1px);
    -o-transform: translateZ(1px);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(1px);
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 4em;
    height: 80px;
}
div.up {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    height: 35px;
    z-index: 2;
    background: gray;
    text-align: center;
}
div.up:hover {
    background: teal;
}
div.down {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 35px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: gray;
    text-align: center;
}
div.down:hover {
    background: teal;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var imageHeight = ($("#column").height() - 70) / 4;
var imageWidth = imageHeight * 2.3360655737704918032786885245902;
$("#column").width(imageWidth);
var scrollDifference = $("#carousel").height() - $("#column").height();
var movedOn = false;
var incrementPixel = 0;
var c = 6;
var moveCarousel;
$("#carousel > .carouselunit:first-child").addClass("marker");

if (!movedOn) {
    moveCarousel = setInterval(repeatedFunction, 20);
}

function repeatedFunction() {
    if ((!movedOn)) {
        $("#carousel").css({
            top: "-=1"
        });
        console.log("Carousel Height: " + $("#carousel").height());
        console.log("Scroll Difference: " + ($("#carousel").height() - $("#column").height()));
        console.log("Carousel Top Movement: " + $("#carousel").offset().top);
        incrementPixel++;
        console.log("Marker Position: " + $(".marker").offset().top);
        console.log($("#carousel").height() / c);
        if (incrementPixel >= $("#carousel").height() / c) {
            incrementPixel = 0;
            c++;
            $(".marker").clone(true, true).insertAfter("#carousel > .carouselunit:last-child").removeClass("marker");
            $(".marker").removeClass("marker").next(".carouselunit").addClass("marker");
            console.log("Carousel Position After Cloning Whatever is Marker: " + $("#carousel").offset().top);
            console.log("Moving Marker Down - Marker Position After Cloning New One: " + $(".marker").offset().top);
            console.log("Scroll Difference: " + scrollDifference);
        }
    }
}

//MOUSE WHEEL EVENT
$("#carousel").on('mousewheel', function (event) {
    scrollDifference = $("#carousel").height() - $("#column").height();
    var scrollIncrement = $("#carousel").height() / (6 * 3);
    if (!movedOn) {
        clearInterval(moveCarousel);
        var positionOfNewFirstImage = $(".marker").offset().top;
        $(".marker").prevAll().remove();
        c = 6;
        $("#carousel").css({
            top: positionOfNewFirstImage - 35
        });
        movedOn = true;
    }
    if (event.deltaY > 0) {//SCROLL UP
        if ((scrollDifference > 0) && ($("#carousel").offset().top < 0)) {
            if ($("#carousel").offset().top + scrollIncrement > 0) {
                var difference = $("#carousel").offset().top + scrollIncrement;
                $(this).css({
                    top: "+=" + (scrollIncrement - difference)
                }, 80);
                if ($(".flipcard.nonselectedhover")) {
                    $(".flipcard.nonselectedhover").css({
                        top: "+=" + (scrollIncrement - difference)
                    });
                }
            } else {
                $(this).css({
                    top: "+=" + scrollIncrement
                }, 80);
                console.log("Position of carousel after scroll: " + $("#carousel").offset().top);
                if ($(".flipcard.nonselectedhover")) {
                    $(".flipcard.nonselectedhover").css({
                        top: "+=" + scrollIncrement
                    });
                }
            }
        }

    }
    else if (event.deltaY < 0) {//SCROLL DOWN
        if ((scrollDifference > 0) && ($("#carousel").offset().top > -scrollDifference - 70)) {

            if ($("#carousel").offset().top - scrollIncrement < -scrollDifference - 70) {
                var differenceDown = Math.abs(scrollDifference + 70 + ($("#carousel").offset().top - scrollIncrement));
                $(this).css({
                    top: "-=" + (scrollIncrement - differenceDown)
                }, 80);
                console.log("Going up " + (scrollIncrement - differenceDown) + " pixels.");
                console.log("carousel going up with modified increment");
                console.log("Position of carousel after scroll: " + $("#carousel").offset().top);
                if ($(".flipcard.nonselectedhover")) {
                    $(".flipcard.nonselectedhover").css({
                        top: "-=" + (scrollIncrement - differenceDown)
                    });
                }
            }
            else {
                $(this).css({
                    top: "-=" + scrollIncrement
                }, 80);
                console.log("Going up " + scrollIncrement + " pixels.");
                console.log("carousel going up with regular increment");
                console.log("Position of carousel after scroll: " + $("#carousel").offset().top);
                if ($(".flipcard.nonselectedhover")) {
                    $(".flipcard.nonselectedhover").css({
                        top: "-=" + scrollIncrement
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

$("#carousel").mouseenter(function () {
    if (!$(this).children(".carouselunit").children(".flipcard").hasClass("selected")) {
        if (!movedOn) {
            clearInterval(moveCarousel);
            var positionOfNewFirstImage = $(".marker").offset().top;
            console.log("Mouse enter carousel to stop it");
            console.log("Position of new first image, Marker: " + positionOfNewFirstImage);
            $(".marker").prevAll().remove();
            c = 6;
            $("#carousel").css({
                top: positionOfNewFirstImage - 35
            });
            movedOn = true;
        }
    }
});

$("#carousel").mouseleave(function () {
    movedOn = false;
    if (!$(this).children(".carouselunit").children(".flipcard").hasClass("selected")) {
        if (!movedOn) {
            moveCarousel = setInterval(repeatedFunction, 20);
        }
    }
});
```